# Plotting the solution of diffusion equation for multiple times using SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I want to plot this equation for different times. So time is supposed to be constant, x should vary and then plot y? this equation is the analytic solution of the The Time Dependent Diffusion Equation.

my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import diags
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse
from scipy import special
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Canalytical(intervals, D=1):

    points = 1000

    x=np.linspace(0, 1, intervals+1)
    t=1
    c=np.ones([intervals+1])

    sm = 0
    pos = 0

    for xi in x:

        for i in range(points):

            sm+=sp.special.erfc((1-xi+2*i)/(2*np.sqrt(D*t))) + 
                sp.special.erfc((1+xi+2*i)/(2*np.sqrt(D*t)))

        c[pos] = sm
        pos += 1
        sm = 0

    return c, x

c, xi = Canalytical(intervals=1000) 
plt.plot(xi, c)
plt.show()
```

[image: I want to plot this equation]

Comment: after running it for multiple times I have the function moving upwards as t approaches 1. Is this the problem you were talking about?

Comment: thanks but I want the exact same behavior as it is in the attached figure. But for t=1 my model can not predict the same line as it is for t=1 in the figure.

Comment: I'm finding with the current setup that the summation does not effect the output of the graph much at all. I dont see a difference between a single term and 1000

Comment: Could you provide a source for the equation referenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation in the image is wrong. Plug x = 0 in it, and you'll see it's not zero. The sign in front of the second erfc function should have been `-`.

The time `t` should be passed to Canalytical as a parameter, so the function can be used for multiple values of t.

Using 1000 terms of the sum is excessive since `erfc` decays extremely fast at infinity. `erfc(10)` is about `2e-45`, well beyond machine precision, let alone the resolution of the plot.

Also, consider using **vectorization** when evaluating functions with NumPy. The entire array `x` can be passed to the function at once, eliminating the loop. This is what remains:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def Canalytical(intervals, t=1, D=1):
    points = 1000
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, intervals+1)
    c = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(points):
        c += special.erfc((1-x+2*i)/(2*np.sqrt(D*t))) - special.erfc((1+x+2*i)/(2*np.sqrt(D*t)))
    return x, c
plt.plot(*Canalytical(intervals=1000, t=1)) 
plt.plot(*Canalytical(intervals=1000, t=0.1)) 
plt.plot(*Canalytical(intervals=1000, t=0.01)) 
plt.plot(*Canalytical(intervals=1000, t=0.001)) 
plt.show()
```

with the output

[image: plot]